# Equivalence between Gibbs measures and conformal measures

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, symbolic-dynamics

I was reading an article about Gibbs measures, but the author defines Gibbs measures in a different way than the usual (which is done by using conditional expectations). The way that he defines I have already seen in the literature as conformal measures. More precisely, that's what he does: let $\mathcal{A}$ be finite alphabet and consider $X$ a subshift in $\mathbb{Z}$, ie, $X \subset \mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{Z}}$. Let $T\colon X \rightarrow X$ denote the shift map and define the double tail relation as the following:

Define $\Gamma_X = \{(x, y) \in X \times X \hspace{2mm}: \hspace{2mm} \lim_{|n| \rightarrow +\infty} d(T^nx, T^ny) = 0\}$.

Now, consider a function $f\colon X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with summable variation and define 
$$\phi_f(x, y) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \left[f(T^ny) - f(T^nx)\right]. $$

A measure $\mu$ is Gibbs if it is $\Gamma_X$-non-singular and $\frac{d \mu \circ T}{d\mu} = \exp(\phi_f(x, Tx))$.

I was wondering if you know where can I find a reference about that. I have already found something similar to that in one of Sarig's book, but it is not exactly what I need and I having trouble trying to generalize that!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide the paper you refer to ? Also, which "usual" definition are you using ?